# Preg_replace wont remove each img tag with src address

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, html-parsing

I am working on my PHP to search for the images that come the specific address so I want to remove all of these img tags.

I have the img tags which show like this:

```
<img src="http://example.com/someimage1.jpeg">
<img src="http://example.com/someimage2.jpeg">
<img src="http://example.com/someimage3.jpeg">
<img src="http://example.com/someimage4.jpeg">
<img style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 0px; MAX-HEIGHT: 0px" alt="" src="http://test.mydomain.com/project433q325/track/Images/signature.gif?id=446&amp;etc=1586624376">
```

When I try this:

```
foreach ($src as $image) {
    $image = preg_replace("\<img src\=\"(.+)\"(.+)\/\>/i", '', $src);
}
```

It will not remove the img tag, so I have also tried this:

```
foreach ($src as $image) {
    $image = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $src); 
}
```

I still have the same issue as it will not remove the img tag.

Here is the full code:

```
if (strpos($inbox_message, 'http://test.mydomain.com/project433q325/track/Images/signature.gif?') !== false) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($inbox_message);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");

    if ($src) {
        foreach ($src as $image) {
            //image->nodeValue = preg_replace('<img.*?src='.$src.'.*?/>!i', '', $src);
            //$src = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $src);
            $image = preg_replace("\<img src\=\"(.+)\"(.+)\/\>/i", '', $src);
        //}
    }
    $inbox_message = $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

What I am trying to do is I only want to search for the img tags that have the src address which show 'http://test.mydomain.com/project433q325/track/Images/signature.gif?' and remove them.

Can you please show me an example how I can search for each img tag that have specific src address so I can remove each img tags using preg_replace?

Thank you.

**EDIT: Here is the $inbox_message variable:**

```
$inbox_message = '<img src="http://example.com/someimage1.jpeg"><img src="http://example.com/someimage2.jpeg"><img src="http://example.com/someimage3.jpeg"><img src="http://example.com/someimage4.jpeg"><img style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 0px; MAX-HEIGHT: 0px" alt="" src="http://test.mydomain.com/project433q325/track/Images/signature.gif?id=446&amp;etc=1586624376">';
```

Comment: Using regexs to manipulate HTML can cause all sorts of problems, I would recommend using a DOM parser (DOMDocument and loadHTML).

Comment: As I have tried it and it wont remove it.

Comment: @NigelRen Can you please post the source of what I should use to remove each img tag using with DOM parser?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445352/dom-php-delete-all-tags-by-tag-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use a regex for this. You can use your `strpos` as you were but move it inside the DOM parsing and compare each `img`. You can then use `removeChild()` to remove the appropriate images. (This is an adapted answer from [How to delete element with DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument))

```
<?php
$inbox_message = '<p> Keep This</p><img src="http://example.com/someimage1.jpeg"><img src="http://example.com/someimage2.jpeg"><img src="http://example.com/someimage3.jpeg"><img src="http://example.com/someimage4.jpeg"><h1>Fake element</h1><img style="OVERFLOW: hidden; WIDTH: 0px; MAX-HEIGHT: 0px" alt="" src="http://test.mydomain.com/project433q325/track/Images/signature.gif?id=446&amp;etc=1586624376">';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($inbox_message);
$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
for($i = $imgs->length; --$i >= 0;){
    $node = $imgs->item($i);
    if (strpos($node->getAttribute('src'), 'http://test.mydomain.com/project433q325/track/Images/signature.gif?') !== false) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
echo $doc->savehtml();
```

https://3v4l.org/qinLR

You also could use [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) if `$node->getAttribute('src')` might contain varying case. The needle for `strpos` should also be lowercased in that case.

For regex issues...

```
preg_replace("\<img src\=\"(.+)\"(.+)\/\>/i", '', $src);
```

The start of the regex is attempting to use a backslash which is not a valid [delimiter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). `A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.` The starting delimiter must match the ending delimiter. Additionally your `$src` only contained the value of the attribute so `<img src...` would never match.

If you were to get that functioning the `.+` would need to be replaced with the URI you wanted to check against.

BUT regex really is the wrong approach here. Use a parser, as you were, for these type of jobs. Regex shouldn't be used for structured data. If it is structured there likely already are functions written for it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all `img` tags, use the following regex pattern:

```
<img\s+[^>]+>
```

https://regex101.com/r/HfStzZ/1

---

To include the specific `src` url as you described in your question, use the following regex pattern:

```
<img\s+[^>]*\bsrc="[^"]*\/signature\.gif[^\>]*\>
```

https://regex101.com/r/HfStzZ/2

---

In PHP, use the `preg_replace` command as follows:

```
$output = preg_replace('/<img\s+[^>]*\bsrc="[^"]*\/signature\.gif[^\>]*\>/', '', $input);
```

Comment: I have tried this `$inbox_message = preg_replace('<img\s+[^>]*\bsrc="http:\/\/test\.mydomain\.com\/project433q325\/track\/Images\/signature\.gif[^\>]*\>', "", $inbox_message);` it wont remove it. Please help.